# UIToolbar with UIBarButtonItems - button lights up, but selector not called

Tags: objective-c, selector, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I've build a UIToolbar with UIBarButtonItems which I have added as follows:

```
self.pdfBar1.items = @[self.openLibraryTable1Button, self.pdf1SearchBarButton, self.exportDoc1Button];
```

The buttons I've created before as follows:

```
self.openLibraryTable1Button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize target:self action:@selector(openFileButtonLeft:)];
self.exportDoc1Button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(exportButton1Pressed:)];
self.pdf1SearchBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(showSearch1:)];
```

The problem is that when pressing the buttons, the buttons light up, but the selectors are not called.

Oddly enough, when I tab-hold on a different part of the screen, and simultaneously tab the button, then the selector is called.

Not sure if it's related, but the pdfBar1 toolbar is a subview of another view:

```
[_pdfVC1View addSubview:self.pdfBar1];
```

Which itself is part of the main view

```
[self.view addSubview:_pdfVC1View];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: items added after alloc method?

Comment: did you implement any gesture over the view?